# Cannot allocate memory space in my win 10 OS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I recently bought a new SSD.I put the SSD in the HDD slot.Also I put in the HDD in CD drive slot for storage. I installed WIN 10 home(from windows site) in SSD. I also can see the old windows local drive in THIS PC. So then I tried to format the old wondows local drive and merge it with some other drive. But unfortunately when I formatted the OLD WINDOWS disk, it cannot be able to merge with other local disks. But I can clearly see the 190 GB of space is shown unallocated in the disk partition properties. I tried to merge with the HDD drive's local disk. Maybe it's because of the temporary cache recovery is preventing it from operations.[disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aacji.png) [creating new simple volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB4s0.png) [after pressing finish button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cminI.png) Help me to retrieve the unallocated memory.

Comment: You cannot merge a partition from Disk 1 with a partition on Disk 0. You also have no partitions on Disk 1 that can be merged with the unallocated space on Disk 1.  *You can only merge partitions that follow another one another.*

Comment: what about the unallocated space cant i use it'

Comment: @John - You might want to read the question again, the partition on Disk 1 that contained Windows, was already removed.  This question has nothing to do with the `Windows.old` directory.

Comment: windows old is not its name. its just local disk C(which had windows 10 OS ultimate).When I formatted it, the 190GB space turned unallocated